# Rsync multiple folder from source and destination and only specific file

Tags: linux, rsync

I have a scenario here, have  multiple folder at source /opt/dir1 /opt/dir2 .... and create folder name to /var/www/html/dir1, /var/www/html/dir2,...  and one specific file extension like *.txt from source under all dir /opt/dir1 /opt/dir2...

Comment: You need to be a lot clearer is what you're asking. Do you only want to copy *.txt files? Give examples of source file listing including directories and what you want the destination to look like.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I have multiple folder on remote directory with different files like pdf, txt on remote server, create exact same directory name to local server and copy only txt file from remote server

Answer (score 0):

You may use `--exclude` and `--include` in order to filter what you want to rsync around.

i.e.

```
rsync -av --include=*.txt --exclude=* /opt/ destination:/var/www/html/
```

Source:

```
rsync --help

--exclude=PATTERN       exclude files matching PATTERN
--include=PATTERN       don't exclude files matching PATTERN
```